# VC++においてconstexprのoperatorの中で範囲for文が動かない

Tags: c++, visual-c++

自分の環境のみで起こる現象か確認したいコードがあります。

Visual Studio 2019 Community Ver16.4

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    constexpr Test() : elements{ 1,2,3 } {
    }
    constexpr Test& operator+=(double s) {
        for (auto&& p : elements)
            p += s;
        return *this;
    }
    double elements[3];
};

int main(){
    constexpr auto res1 = Test{} += 3.0;
    std::cout << "res1(constexpr)" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& p : res1.elements)
        std::cout << p << std::endl;

    auto res2 = Test{} += 3.0;
    std::cout << "res2" << std::endl;
    for (auto&& p : res2.elements)
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

wandboxのclangやGCC、visual studioでもclang-clの場合は期待通りに動きます。
プラットフォームをVisual Studio 2019 (v142)にしたときのみconstexprのoperator内のforループが動いてないような結果がでるのです。

Visual Studioでの結果（res1の結果がおかしい）

```
res1(constexpr)
1
2
3
res2
4
5
6
```

[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8aghr4S9mqKFIUpu)での結果（期待した結果）

```
res1(constexpr)
4
5
6
res2
4
5
6
```

Comment: ここ [Microsoft C++ 言語の準拠表](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) とかここ [Visual Studio の C++ 準拠の強化](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements?view=vs-2019) に資料があるようですので、どの項目に対応する内容なのか調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 1個:P0184R0 範囲ベースの for-loop (汎用)が対応済みで、2個:P0962R2 範囲 for ループのカスタマイゼーション ポイントを見つけるルールの緩和, P0614R1 初期化を使う範囲ベースの for-loop が未対応のようですが、どちらかに当てはまるのでしょうか。

Comment: constexprのoperatorでなければ期待した結果になります。またC++14以降であれば動く筈のコードですのでP0962R2とP0614R1は違うと思います。

Comment: そうしたら、VisualStudioIDEの画面右上のフィードバックの送信でバグ報告してみたらどうでしょう？ こちらで簡単に試してみた結果も同じになりました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。